# nginx returns error 500 when doing nagios check

Tags: nginx

Please help resolve the following problem.

I am checking HTTP using Nagios and faced with the following error:

```
check_http -H 192.0.0.1
HTTP CRITICAL: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error - 3471 bytes in 0.104 second response time |time=0.103675s;;;0.000000 size=3471B;;;0
Toggle HighlightingOpen in New WindowSelect All
```

I am trying to check if HTTP is available on my external server (`192.0.0.1`). On that server I have nginx as a reverse proxy and Apache. Default directory for nginx is `/usr/share/nginx/www` which has a site in it with permissions as user:user.

nginx is running under the `www-data` user. I have tried adding nagios user to the group of `www-data` with no effect. What causing this problem?

Thanks for assistance.

**UPDATE**

nginx does not write errors to the error_log but to the access_log:

```
172.0.0.1 - - [20/Jan/2012:09:27:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 3094 "-" "check_http/v1.4.14 (nagios-plugins 1.4.14)"
```

where `172.0.0.1` is the nagios server IP address.

**UPDATE 2**

nginx listen to the port 80:

```
andrew@office:~$ telnet 192.0.0.1 80
Trying 1.0.0.192...
Connected to 192.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

**UPDATE 3**

When I access `192.0.0.1` in the browser, I have the error 500 in the logs:

```
192.0.1.1 - - [20/Jan/2012:09:30:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 3094 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7"
192.0.1.1 - - [20/Jan/2012:09:30:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 3094 "http://192.0.0.1/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7"
```

where `192.0.1.1` is my WAN IP.

Comment: TL;DR "I have an error, please fix it". What do you get if you run `curl http://192.0.0.1/`? What about trying `telnet`, have you looked in your NGINX log? Does the site work for other users/computers?

Comment: You said that nginx is acting as a reverse proxy for Apache.  What do you see in Apache's error logs for this request?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you have not provided enough information I'm affraid. Error 500 can have many causes, and you need to leek deeper yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Nagios will do what every user does, it will try to access a certain page. If that page can not be served you get a 404 error or you get a 201 with the page. However you are getting a 500 error meaning an internal server error. So there is a bad configuration your Nginx server because it can not server the page when Nagios requests it. You are getting a Critical error from Nagios, meaning Nagios is working but it sees there is a problem with your webserver.

The problem lies within your Nginx server and not Nagios. I suggest reading the error logs from Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for looking on this. You helped to identify the problem.
I have solved this issue by adding:

```
if ($REMOTE_ADDR = "nagio_server_ip") {
    rewrite .* http://www.example.com last;
}
```

to my default nginx host configuration (under the `location /` section).